# Wix Load items into ComboBox

Tags: wix, wix3.6, wix-extension, wixlib

I need to use custom action to load items into combobox.

UI.wxs:

```
            <Control Id="Server" Type="ComboBox" X="30" Y="65" Width="200" Height="18" Property="DATABASE_SERVER">
                <ComboBox Property="DATABASE_SERVER">
                    <ListItem Text="[DATABASE_SERVER]" Value="[DATABASE_SERVER]" />
                </ComboBox>
                <Publish Property="LOGON_VALID" Value="0">1</Publish>
            </Control>
```

Custom Action

```
private static ActionResult EnumSqlServersIntoComboBox(Session session, IEnumerable<DataRow> rows)
{
    try
    {
        Debugger.Break();

        session.Log("EnumSQLServers: Begin");

        // Grab the combo box but make sure I'm getting only the one 
        // from WebAppInstallDlg.
        View view = session.Database.OpenView("SELECT * FROM ComboBox WHERE ComboBox.Property='DATABASE_SERVER'");
        view.Execute();

        Int32 index = 1;
        session.Log("EnumSQLServers: Enumerating SQL servers");
        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
        {
            String serverName = row["Name"].ToString();

            // Create a record for this web site. All I care about is
            // the name so use it for fields three and four.
            session.Log("EnumSQLServers: Processing SQL server: {0}", serverName);

            Record record = session.Database.CreateRecord(4);
            record.SetString(1, "DATABASE_SERVER");
            record.SetInteger(2, index);
            record.SetString(3, serverName);
            record.SetString(4, serverName);

            session.Log("EnumSQLServers: Adding record");
            view.Modify(ViewModifyMode.InsertTemporary, record);
            index++;
        }

        view.Close();

        session.Log("EnumSQLServers: End");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        session.Log("EnumSQLServers: exception: {0}", ex.Message);
        throw;
    }

    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a input text box with drop down arrow next to it with all loaded sql servers.
[image]

***The only time sql servers get loaded into combobox is when I change my UI code to this:***

```
<Control Type="ComboBox" Property="DATABASE_SERVER" Id="Server" Width="180" Height="16" X="110" Y="60" ComboList="yes" Sorted="yes" />
```

Notice **ComboList="yes"** item. BUT this won't work for me since this makes the combobox a drop down item and I want to be able to "TYPE" in alternate option.

Comment: Got it working:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480837/wix-create-database-using-windows-authentication][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480837/wix-create-database-using-windows-authentication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out:

Dialogs.wxs:

```
...                <Control Id="ServerLabel" Type="Text" X="20" Y="62" Width="80" Height="25" NoPrefix="yes" Text="SQL Database:" />
                <Control Id="Server" Type="ComboBox" Height="16" Width="180" X="110" Y="60" Property="DATABASE_SERVER">
                    <ComboBox Property="DATABASE_SERVER">
                        <ListItem Text="[DATABASE_SERVER]" Value="[DATABASE_SERVER]" />
                    </ComboBox>
                    <Publish Property="LOGON_VALID" Value="0">1</Publish>
                </Control>
...
```

CustomAction:

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult EnumerateSqlServers(Session session)
    {
        if (null == session)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("session");
        }

        session.Log("EnumerateSQLServers: Begin");

        // Check if running with admin rights and if not, log a message to
        // let them know why it's failing.
        if (false == HasAdminRights())
        {
            session.Log("EnumerateSQLServers: " + "ATTEMPTING TO RUN WITHOUT ADMIN RIGHTS");
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }

        ActionResult result;

        DataTable dt = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(false);
        DataRow[] rows = dt.Select(string.Empty, "IsLocal desc, Name asc");
        result = EnumSqlServersIntoComboBox(session, rows);

        session.Log("EnumerateSQLServers: End");
        return result;
    }

    private static ActionResult EnumSqlServersIntoComboBox(Session session, IEnumerable<DataRow> rows)
    {
        try
        {
            //Debugger.Break();

            session.Log("EnumSQLServers: Begin");

            View view = session.Database.OpenView("DELETE FROM ComboBox WHERE ComboBox.Property='DATABASE_SERVER'");
            view.Execute();

            view = session.Database.OpenView("SELECT * FROM ComboBox");
            view.Execute();

            Int32 index = 1;
            session.Log("EnumSQLServers: Enumerating SQL servers");
            foreach (DataRow row in rows)
            {
                String serverName = row["Name"].ToString();

                // Create a record for this web site. All I care about is
                // the name so use it for fields three and four.
                session.Log("EnumSQLServers: Processing SQL server: {0}", serverName);

                Record record = session.Database.CreateRecord(4);
                record.SetString(1, "DATABASE_SERVER");
                record.SetInteger(2, index);
                record.SetString(3, serverName);
                record.SetString(4, serverName);

                session.Log("EnumSQLServers: Adding record");
                view.Modify(ViewModifyMode.InsertTemporary, record);
                index++;
            }

            view.Close();

            session.Log("EnumSQLServers: End");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            session.Log("EnumSQLServers: exception: {0}", ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```