# How can I test My SQL server credentials in a Wix setup

Tags: sql-server, wix, connection

I want to create a setup using **Wix** that can also run database scripts in SQL server.
So i want to test whether the instance **name**, **username** and **password** provided by the user are correct or not.
ie Connection with the SQL server database can be established with the provided credentials or not.
Is there any way to know that without using Custom actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know why you are saying NO to custom action.Your Problem Can be easily solved using Custom Action.
I am not sure but I believe SqlDatabase Element will attempt to login to your database using credentials provided in User tag. [Example](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/sql/creating-a-database)
And If this dont work I recommend you to try using Custom Action. Refer below links:
    1> [WIX database deployment, installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480837/wix-database-deployment-installation)
    2> AppSecInc has its Open Source wix extension
http://code.dblock.org/msi-community-extensions-deploying-databases
    3> CPP Custom Action
http://benschwehn.wordpress.com/2007/10/16/msi-setup-how-to-do-a-sql-server-connection-test-2/
    4> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331368/WIXDataBase