# Building an installshield installer that deploys a database to SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installshield

We have a project in Visual Studio 2013 that uses Installshield LE to build an installer for a number of C# projects within our Visual Studio solution.

This works great for the .exes, .dlls, and config files.  I've been tasked with automating building our database from a Visual Studio SQL Server Project and deploying it via the installer.

Does anybody have any idea how to do this?  It appears Installshield can run .sql scripts when deploying but that's about it.

Ideally I'd like directly include the .sqlproj (SQL Server Project) "output" as part of the installer process.

Comment: If you get really stuck I recommend you look at doing it in WiX. Googling "Deploy SQL Database WiX" brings up some examples. for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480837/wix-database-deployment-installation or maybe this http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/sql/creating-a-database

Comment: Can you not write a console application that runs the sql for you during install ?

Comment: What about `generate script` in sql server?

Comment: What we did in the past is generated a script to create a database and then we would just execute it as part of the stored procedure calls. we had to separate table creations, stored procedures, triggers, etc. into separate calls. let me know if you are interested, as I still have some stuff left over, which I can share.