# run wix batch script as elevated/admin

Tags: c#, wix, wixsharp

I have written a WIX Installer using wixsharp that wraps a legacy installation procedure that used a batch file.
When running the MSI as an non-admin I do get prompted to elevate (the UAC dialog) however the batch script is run as a non-admin

```
var project = new Project(string.Format("App");
project.Actions = new[] { new PathFileAction(@"C:\build\build_script.bat", args[1], @"C:\build\", Return.check, When.After, Step.InstallExecute, Condition.NOT_Installed, Sequence.InstallExecuteSequence) };
project.UI = WUI.WixUI_InstallDir;
```

One way around this is to start a command prompt as Administrator and run the MSI using msiexec - this works but is very clunky.

**How can I make my `PathFileAction` run as Administrator?**

Answer (score 1):

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484478/run-execommand-in-customaction-as-administrator-mode-in-wix-installer) which is based on pure WIX - you need to add `Execute='deferred' Impersonate='no'` to the output xml so in wixsharp this is possible via `Attributes`...

```
var publishAction = new PathFileAction(@"C:\build\build_script.bat"...
publishAction.Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
{ 
    {"Execute", "deferred"}, 
    {"Impersonate", "no"} 
};
```

UPDATE: this will run the script as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` - if you want to run it as yourself (with elevated permissions) it appears this [is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484478/run-execommand-in-customaction-as-administrator-mode-in-wix-installer)

Comment: publishAction has properties: Impersonate = false and Execute = Execute.deferred, so no need set from attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the contents of build_script.bat but I assume it's installing the MSI silently.  In this scenario UAC prompts aren't possible so the installer exits out with a no priv failure.  You have to run the .bat file elevated or you have to "bless" the MSI by advertising (msiexec /jm)  it first so that it'll self elevate in place from the non elevated user process.

Comment: Chris I am trying `msiexec /jm` now however it already self elevates (presumably so it can be registered in add/remove programs?)

Comment: Chris, after running `msiexec /jm App.Msi` in an admin command prompt I get this `you do not have sufficient priviledges to completes the re-advestiment of this product. Re-Advestisment requires initiation by a local system account calling the MsiAdvertiseScript API, such as through the Group Policy Software Deployment`