# WIX Combobox populating Values

Tags: wix, wix3.7

IS there anyone know how to populate values into combobox using WIX Setup.AS i am trying for past weeks.I couldn't able to achieve this the combobox is not appearing when tries to execute my MSI.Below providing what i doing.Please help me.

```
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProjectComboTest" Level="1">
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>

<UI>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree" />
  <ComboBox Property="WIX_VERSIONS">
    <ListItem Value="Windows Installer XML 3.0" />
    <ListItem Value="Windows Installer XML 3.5" />
    <ListItem Value="Windows Installer XML 3.6" />
  </ComboBox>
  <Dialog Id="MyCustomDlg"  Width="500" Height="260">
    <Control Id="ComboBoxMain" Type="ComboBox" X="10" Y="60" Width="300" Height="17" Property="WIX_VERSIONS" />
    <Control Id="ButtonMain" Type="PushButton" X="320" Y="60" Width="40" Height="17" Text="Show">
      <Publish Property="COMBOVALUEFORMATTED" Order="1"  Value="You've chosen the [WIX_VERSIONS] version of the toolset" />
    </Control>
    <Control Id="LabelMain" Type="Text" X="10" Y="80" Width="360" Height="17" Property="COMBOVALUEFORMATTED" Text="[COMBOVALUEFORMATTED]" />

  </Dialog>
</UI>
```

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProjectComboTest" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
        <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
        <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
            <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
        <!-- </Component> -->
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just try this solution:

```
<Control Id="ComboBoxMain" Type="ComboBox" X="10" Y="60" Width="300" Height="17" Property="WIX_VERSIONS" >
    <ComboBox Property="WIX_VERSIONS">
        <ListItem Value="Windows Installer XML 3.0" />
        <ListItem Value="Windows Installer XML 3.5" />
        <ListItem Value="Windows Installer XML 3.6" />
    </ComboBox>
</Control>
```

Comment: Do you know, if there is option to populate values from Custom Action? I would like to fetch options from server

Comment: This may be a solution for custom item loader: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455542/wix-load-items-into-combobox

Comment: Just a tip if you also put a entry like 
    <Property Id="WIX_VERSIONS" Value="Windows Installer XML 3.0"/> it will be selected by default