# WIX Toolset Customized Dialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dialog, wix

I would like a setup screen with a dropdown list of directory options based on my company's installed software. Is there a way that I can customize the first setup/installation dialog window using C#?

Thank you!

Comment: This is more or less easy - first run a custom action to get the data, then populate the combobox table, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455542/wix-load-items-into-combobox

Comment: Zaitsman, thanks for the input. I figured out that I was having problems because all my dropdown options had the same value, and that throws an error. I figured it out though. If you put your answer as a reply to my stackoverflow question, I can mark your reply as an answer.