# UI listitem icon property by condition

Tags: windows-installer, listitem, wix3

I have two icon files. And I want to change listitem's icon by condition.
I try to use "Condition, if" but I still failed.
What should I do? Thanks.

This is parts of my code.

```
<Binary Id="Passed" SourceFile="$(sys.SOURCEFILEDIR)passed.ico" />
<Binary Id="Failed" SourceFile="$(sys.SOURCEFILEDIR)failed.ico" />


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Fragment>
        <Property Id="ISVALID_PATH" />
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="CheckDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="System Configuration Check">
                <Control X="20"  Y="50"  Id="ListViewCheck" Type="ListView" Width="340" Height="100" Sorted="no" Property="ListView_Property">
                        <ListView Property="ListView_Property" >
                            <ListItem Text="[ISVALID_PATH]" Value="a" Icon="[IconVar]"/>
                            <ListItem Text="Test item 2" Value="b" Icon="PassedImage"/>
                        </ListView>
                </Control>
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I expected I can change the icon property by my conditions.

Comment: Finally, I found the answer.
Like this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455542/wix-load-items-into-combobox